# pymongo connection string error but works in mongdb driver .net and mongosh

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a connection string that I am able to connect via MongoDB.Driver .NET and mongosh but when I am using pymongo - throws the error below.

Here is what I am using for pymongo

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('mongodb://user:password@127.0.0.1:27033')

for db in client.list_databases():
    print(db)
```

This is what I have for .NET

```
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://user:password@127.0.0.1:27033");
var database = client.GetDatabase("database");
var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("collection");
```

and this is what I use for mongosh

```
mongosh  mongodb://user:password@127.0.0.1:27033
```

I am able to connect with .NET and mongosh but not pymongo with the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\us60684\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1686, in list_databases
    res = admin._retryable_read_command(cmd, session=session)
  File "C:\Users\us60684\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\database.py", line 613, in _retryable_read_command
    return self.__client._retryable_read(
  File "C:\Users\us60684\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1305, in _retryable_read
    server = self._select_server(
  File "C:\Users\us60684\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1137, in _select_server
    server = topology.select_server(server_selector)
  File "C:\Users\us60684\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 242, in select_server
    servers = self.select_servers(
  File "C:\Users\us60684\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 200, in select_servers
    server_descriptions = self._select_servers_loop(
  File "C:\Users\us60684\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 216, in _select_servers_loop
    raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: mongodb-rs-2.mongodb-rs-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed,mongodb-rs-0.mongodb-rs-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed,mongodb-rs-1.mongodb-rs-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 627ad1f7d3b2c705e2c52e52, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('mongodb-rs-0.mongodb-rs-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('mongodb-rs-0.mongodb-rs-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')>, <ServerDescription ('mongodb-rs-1.mongodb-rs-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('mongodb-rs-1.mongodb-rs-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')>, <ServerDescription ('mongodb-rs-2.mongodb-rs-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('mongodb-rs-2.mongodb-rs-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')>]>
```

Comment: A `getaddrinfo` failure means a DNS lookup problem.  You have triple-checked the spelling of that very long domain name?

Comment: @TimRoberts - I don't actually type out that long string, it is port forwarded to the IP address.

Comment: I'm not sure I believe that.  If it was just a port forward, why would `pymongo` know about that name?

Comment: @TimRoberts okay